# Connect to Oracle from Sybase

Tags: oracle, sybase

For complicated reasons (aren't they always) I need to query an Oracle table from a Sybase view. Any thoughts of how I can do this?

example oracle con details: 
  database: dta@mydomain.com
  schema: dta
  pwd: 123

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the data live you'll need a gateway.[Oracle Database Gateways](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/gateways/index.html)

If there can be a delay, you might be better off doing a periodic data export and then using an external table.[Oracle External Tables](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/oracle9i/daily/sept19.html)